# How do I pass an optional flag to other Python Script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

How do I pass an optional flag to other Python Script?
I have written this code below:

```
argument_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argument_parser.add_argument('-validation', help="it is for validation", action="store_true")
arguments = argument_parser.parse_args()

release_exe_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '__release__.py')
proc = subprocess.Popen(args=[python_exe_path, release_exe_path, '--mode', arguments.mode, '-project', arguments.project, '-site', arguments.site,'-validation'])
proc.wait()
```

but this gives error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

what should be the actual code?

Comment: AFAIK, argparse isn't happy with arguments of the form `-validation`.  It usually needs to have double dashes if it is a multiletter argument.  e.g. `-a` is OK, but `-argparse` isn't (it should be `--argparse`).  I doubt that this will solve the problem that you're seeing, but it'll solve another problem that you'll probably have later on.

Comment: Also, where is the `TypeError` happening?  Can you edit your post including the full traceback?

Comment: @mgilson, afaik, argparse is perfectly happy with parsing single-dash long options.

Comment: @gvalkov -- You might be correct.  I just hacked together a quick test script to see and it worked.  I still can't shake the feeling that I've seen something like this before and that there was a subtle gotcha involved ... But maybe it's because I don't like it from an API standpoint.

Comment: You're thinking of optparse - it wouldn't accept '-validation' as a valid option :)

Comment: if i write like
if arguments.validation == True:
        project = 'Validation'
it works
now if i write
proc = subprocess.Popen(args=[PYTHON_EXE_PATH, release_exe_path, '--mode', arguments.mode, '-project', arguments.project, '-site', arguments.site,'-validation',arguments.validation])
it doesn't work

Comment: plz help..anybody can answer this?

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't seem to be the code you ran.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue with argparse. The syntax for the argument is correct as stated by others. Please post a more informative code  snippet.